# If FileExists delete another file

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to add a sub-routine to a VBScript.  In short, I am trying to see if one type of file exists, it will delete another file.

There will be files like:

```
SOCAL_CU59_res.dxf 
SOCAL_CU59_main.dxf 
SOCAL_CU59_mot.dxf
SOCAL_CU59_motl.dxf
```

but on occassion there may be a file with an "x" at the end of the filename:

```
SOCAL_CU59_resx.dxf
SOCAL_CU59_mainx.dxf 
SOCAL_CU59_motx.dxf
SOCAL_CU59_motlx.dxf
```

They would all be in the same folder.  The "x" file has priority.  So if it exist I want to delete the matching file file without the "x".

Here is what I have so far but errors. The check filesize routine I added works great but it's after that I am having no luck:

```
Dim oFSO, sDirectoryPath, oFOLDER, oFile
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sDirectoryPath = "S:\SOCAL\Section_11\Road DXFs\"

RecurseFolders sDirectoryPath

Sub RecurseFolders(sFolder)
  'Here we set the oFolder object, note that its variable scope is within
  'this sub, so you can set it many times and it's value will only be
  'that of the sub that's currently running.
  Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)

  'Here we are looping through every file in the directory path.
  For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'This just checks for a file size less than 100Kb
    If oFile.Size <= 1085 And Right(LCase(oFile.Name),3) = "dxf" Then
      oFile.Delete True
    End If
  Next

  For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'This checks if there is a file with an 'x' at the end of filename
    If FileExists (Right(oFile.Name),1) = "x" Then
      oFile.Delete True
    End If
  Next

  'Here we do the recursive bit. We need to loop through each folder in
  'the directory too and call the same sub to ensure we check every folder
  'in the path.
  For Each oFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
    RecurseFolders oFolder.Path
  Next
End Sub
```

The script creates both files, but does not delete the file that does NOT have the "x". The error says for line 204, Char 5:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'Right'

The line the error refers to is: `If FileExists (Right(oFile.Name),1) = "x" Then`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few inherent problems that you need to correct in order to do this properly.  First, you need to make the parenthesis correction mentioned by Ansgar Wiechers.  Second, you should remove the duplicate loop.  There's no need to loop over all of the files multiple times.  Finally, you should store the files to be deleted until after the loop has finished. Deleting a file while it is in the file set that is currently being looped over could produce unexpected results or unexplained errors.

With that said, here's how I would approach this.  You'll note all of the corrections I've mentioned.

```
Dim oFSO, sDirectoryPath, oFOLDER, oFile
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sDirectoryPath = "S:\SOCAL\Section_11\Road DXFs\"
Dim arrFilesToDelete()  'an empty dynamic array to hold files to be deleted later
Dim i = 0               'an iterator used to track the array pointer

RecurseFolders sDirectoryPath
DeleteExtraFiles arrFilesToDelete

Sub RecurseFolders(sFolder)
    'Here we set the oFolder object, note that its variable scope is within
    'this sub, so you can set it many times and it's value will only be
    'that of the sub that's currently running.
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)

    'Here we are looping through every file in the directory path.
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        'Is the file a "dxf" file
        If LCase(Right(oFile.Name)) = "dxf" Then
            'This just checks for a file size less than 100Kb
            If oFile.Size <= 1085 And Right(LCase(oFile.Name),3) = "dxf" Then

            End If

            'This checks if there is an 'x' at the end of filename
            If LCase(Right(oFile.Name) 5) = "x.dxf" Then
                'if so, store its counterpart for deletion later
                sBadFile = Replace(oFile.Name, "x.dxf", ".dxf")
                ReDim Preserve arrFilesToDelete(i)
                arrFilesToDelete(i) = oFile.Path & "\" & sBadFile
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Here we do the recursive bit. We need to loop through each folder in
    'the directory too and call the same sub to ensure we check every folder
    'in the path.
    For Each oFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        RecurseFolders oFolder.Path
    Next
End Sub

Sub DeleteExtraFiles(arrFiles)
    For Each sFile in arrFiles
        If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
            oFSO.DeleteFile sFile
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nilpo, I pasted your code over mine to try out.  I am getting an error message "Expected end of statement (800A0401)" for LINE 181 CHAR: 22, which refers to:  Dim arrFilesToDelete = Array()

Comment: Sorry!  That what I get for answering VBS questions while programming in another language.  I've corrected that line in my answer.  Please also note that I've added `ReDim` line as well.

Comment: New issues. First got a "Name Redefined" error.  Changed "i" to "t".  New error: "Expected end of statement" for "DIM t = 0".  I changed that to:
DIM t
t = 0 
New error:  "Expected ')'" Added a "," 'If LCase(Right(oFile.Name),5) = "x.dxf" Then'. 
Latest error: "Wrong #of arguments or invalid property assignment' referring to line: 
'If LCase(Right(oFile.Name)) = "dxf" Then'
Am making matters worse by trying to solve each error message as it appears?  Also, line missing 'oFile.Delete True'
after: 'If oFile.Size <= 1085 And Right(LCase(oFile.Name),3) = "dxf" Then'.  Just blank line. ThisCorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You put the inner closing parenthesis in the wrong place. The parameter `1` belongs to the function [`Right`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh8fefz1.aspx). Change this:

```
If FileExists (Right(oFile.Name),1) = "x" Then
```

into this:

```
If FileExists (Right(oFile.Name,1)) = "x" Then
```

With that said, there might be other issues with that line. VBScript doesn't have a built-in function `FileExists` and your code snippet doesn't reveal if that function is implemented elsewhere in your code, so whether passing it a character and comparing its return value to the character `x` actually makes sense is hard to say.

If you meant to use the `FileSystemObject` method [`FileExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t.aspx) you'd need to call it from the actual `FileSystemObject` instance:

```
If oFSO.FileExists(...) Then
```

and pass it a filename or path, not a single character or a boolean value.

If you want to test if for any given file `foo.ext` another file `foox.ext` exists, and in that case delete `foo.ext` you'd do something like this:

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
  xFilename = oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile) & "x." & oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)
  If oFSO.FileExists(oFSO.BuildPath(oFile.Parent, xFilename)) Then
    oFile.Delete True
  End If
Next
```

Comment: The outer parenthesis are also incorrect.  I've corrected them, however, this still doesn't actually do anything.  FileExists will always return false since `Right` returns true or false.

Comment: @Nilpo `FileExists` isn't a built-in function, and the method with that name would have to be called like this: `oFSO.FileExists(...)`. Since we don't know anything about the implementation of a procedure or function `FileExists` I'm not going to make assumptions about what parameters it might expect or what result it might return.

Comment: That's fair. I understand your argument, but I think it's safe to assume it doesn't accept true or false as a parameter.

Comment: Indeed. I was just about to add a respective note to my answer.